# Second minimum salary with grouping

Tags: mysql, sql

I have such kind of table, imagine it's a salary per month for employee with id:

[image]

What query should I use to get **second** minimal salary for each employee?
Result should be smth like:

```
id month amount
 1   2     20
 2   2     30
 3   3     15
```

Comment: I was told it can be solved just with ANSI SQL, but, let it be MySQL, for example.

Comment: You really should provide what query or queries you've tried to achieve what you're after, to show you've at least attempted to solve the problem yourself....

Comment: I've tried smth like: select id, min(amount) from tt group by id HAVING min(amount) > (SELECT min(amount) from tt group by id), but it's a wrong way. Also I thought about 'union', but it can't be used dynamically.

Comment: I gave you an answer using complex joins which does not involve analytic functions.

Comment: Lets say we have (id, month, salary) equal to (1, 1, 10), (1, 2, 10), (1, 3, 20), and (1, 4, 20). Which should be the output: (1, 1, 10) or (1, 2, 10), or both, or (1, 3, 20), or (1, 4, 20) or both? If only the first two records would exist (with salary 10), and not the other two, what then should be the result? Nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ANSI standard SQL, you would use the `dense_rank()` function:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
              dense_rank() over (partition by id order by amount desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 2;
```

Note:  this gives the second largest value.  If there are ties for first, then it gives the second value.

EDIT:

In MySQL, you can do:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.amount = (select t2.amount
                  from t t2
                  where t.id = t2.id
                  order by t2.amount desc
                  limit 1, 1
                 );
```

Note:  this handles ties differently.  It will give the second amount, even if the same as the first.  I'm not sure which you want.

Comment: Smth wrong with 'by', I have such an error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by month order by amount desc) as seqnum from tt ) tt wher' at line 3.

Comment: Gordon's answer is not MySQL though it certainly should work on SQL Server or Oracle.

Comment: Do you know how it can be fixed for MySQL? Thank you.

Comment: It seems solution for MySQL works only if we have 3 rows per id, am I wrong?

Comment: @DmitriiAdonin From Gordon's answer (emphasis mine): "Note: this gives the **second largest** value." You need to change from a descending sort (highest numbers first) to an ascending sort (lowest numbers first) if you want the **second smallest** value.